# Using boost stream_buffer with std::ofstream

Tags: c++, boost, stl, ofstream, ostream

From the [boost iostreams tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/writing_devices.html) I have read that it is possible to use boost stream_buffer with std::ostream, as shown in the tutorial:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> buf("log.txt");
    std::ostream                     out(&buf);
    // out writes to log.txt
}
```

How can we use boost stream_buffer to create std::ofstream? I have implemented a custom sink device that I can use to create a boost stream_buffer. With the stream buffer I am able to create std::ostream, but not std::ofstream.

```
// ...
io::stream_buffer<my_custom_file_sink> mybuf("myfile.txt"); // Creating stream_buffer works
std::ostream out(&mybuf); // Here I would like to use std::ofstream
// ...
```

I needed this because another library that I am using requires std::ofstream&. But unfortunately passing boost stream_buffer to std::ofstream constructor does not compile. Any possible workarounds?

Comment: No. There is no workaround.

Comment: @noxmetus You are going to be surprised then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an `std::ofstream` using its default constructor and then assign your buffer to it:

```
io::stream_buffer<my_custom_file_sink> mybuf("myfile.txt");

std::ofstream out;
out.std::ostream::rdbuf(&mybuf); // Call the base class version.
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The preferable syntax would be "out.std::ostream::rdbuf(&mybuf)", without static_cast. However. Is it a joke? You can't be serious. Or you don't see a problem here, do you? Try to answer this for example: what will happen if I write "std::ofstream ofs = std::move(out);". A hint: std::basic_ofstream stores std::basic_filebuf and accesses it directly.

Comment: @noxmetus Which `ofstream` functions access the buffer directly?

Comment: @noxmetus That syntax slipped out of my mind, thanks for reminding.

Comment: It depends on implementation :-O. But it doesn't matter. With your hack you will get an object with a broken contract. It may work in some cases, but a dude who programs like this should be fired without mercy, unless it's an RCG or an intern.